# Select a PrimeFaces radio button with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write Selenium tests to select a radio button. Below is the html from 'view Source'.

```
<table id="surveyForm:surveyUrlType" class="ui-selectoneradio ui-widget" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input id="surveyForm:surveyUrlType:0" name="surveyForm:surveyUrlType" type="radio" value="TYPED" checked="checked" onchange="com.ssi.feasibility.surveyView.showSurveyType(this);">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
                    <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-bullet"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><label for="surveyForm:surveyUrlType:0">Enter Survey URL</label></td>
        <td>
            <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input id="surveyForm:surveyUrlType:1" name="surveyForm:surveyUrlType" type="radio" value="FILE" onchange="com.ssi.feasibility.surveyView.showSurveyType(this);">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                    <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><label for="surveyForm:surveyUrlType:1">Upload Survey URLs</label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select 'Upload Survey URLs' radio button.

I have tried several different approaches to select the radio button. Here are a few:

```
        $("#surveyForm\\surveyUrlType").click();

        This gives me the error : 
        $("#surveyForm\\:surveyUrlType\\:1").first().click()
```

Error- Element is not clickable at point (809, 367). Other element would receive the click: ...

Below give me NoSuchElementFound:

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("surveyForm:surveyUrlType:1")).click()
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @id='surveyForm\\:surveyUrlType\\:1']")).click()
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='FILE']")).click()
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#surveyForm\\:surveyUrlType\\:1")).click()
```

Below don't give me any error but they also do not select the radio button.

```
        $(".ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default")[1].click()
        $(".ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default").click()
        $("#surveyForm\\:surveyUrlType").find(".ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default").find("span").click()
```

But none of these work. What am I missing?

Comment: It is in Primefaces dialog. I can access other input boxes on the page and manipulate their values. But just this radio button. The first one is pre-selected. I want to select the second one. No I have not tried WebDriverWait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I got it to work finally !!

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='surveyForm\\:surveyUrlType\\:1']")).click()
```

Comment: That code looks like you're clicking on the `label` and not the `input`. Does that really work?

Comment: @vincebowden Yes the `label` has an onclick listener. I'm not sure why the other options failed, but clicking the label works for me with Selenium 2.47.1 and Prime 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(Driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("surveyForm:surveyUrlType:1")));
element.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it and I get this error:     org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (454, 255). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=31.0.1650.63)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.1,platform=Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in Java

```
lst=driver.findElements(by_name("surveyForm:surveyUrlType"))
   for(condition)
      option.click()
```

In python I solved the problem above this way:

```
lst=driver.find_elements_by_name("surveyForm:surveyUrlType")
for i in lst:
   if(i.text=="Enter Survey")
       i.click()
   elif(i.text=="Upload Survey URLs")
       i.click()
```

If the above one haven't helped try this one

```
driver.findElement(by_class_name("ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-bullet")).click()
driver.findElement(by_class_name("ui-radiobutton-icon")).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried all of the suggestions and they did not work. :(